# chat profiles no longer show time details

Tags: feature-request, chat

This may apply to more chat rooms, but it applies at least to the Mathematics chat room.

In the past when hovering over the "last seen" and "last message" times on someone's chat profile, the precise times would appear (similar to an HTML tooltip).  This seems to be the way most abbreviated times work in SE, so I was surprised to see that these hover messages no longer appear for chat profiles. Would it be possible to bring them back?

Comment: If you hover over the time in "asked ... ago" that appears over my sig, it will show "2012-01-25 01:23:55Z"

Comment: This has never worked, you must be confusing it with something else. However, I agree that it would be a good thing to add.

Comment: @balpha: should I change the title and question to be a feature request? I was sure I had used this a few days ago. oh well :-)